# kentico site and DesignMode css conflicts

Tags: kentico

I have my custom css (all Compass/SASS based) added to the site from the Master page, rather than include the CSS in the site settings. While in Design View, my custom css, has overridden the items from DesignMode.css.

My master page is loading in my compiled CSS this way:

```
<link href="/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx?stylesheetfile=/KFF/SalesForce/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

What is the best method to isolate my CSS from the designview.css?

Comment: Should probably just stick to using Kentico tag that way people who don't know what Kentico is won't mark your question as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to take a look at this [article](http://devnet.kentico.com/forums/f49/fp2/t12505/apply-stylesheet-to-site-without-affecting-editor)

I think you can also do something like this in your master page: 
`{% ViewMode == "LiveSite" ? "StyleSheet Link": "" %}`